# How to horizontally align an image inside a div comparing to another div in bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

Suppose i have taken an image inside a column and taken text in another column in bootstrap, now want to align that image at the middle (vertically & horizontally) of that div. How to do that?

My codes are:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="pia-icon-performance.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

the image is not center along with the text. Please help

Answer (score 0):

have you messed about with your margins?

i presume if you get the height of the container minus height of image divide by 2 and add that to a margin-top in css

```
img{
margin-top:100px;}
```

Comment: thanks Patrick, but if the div height is unknown (based on the text amount the div will be big or small) then how to align this with the image div?